# If X surface and $ E=1+v^2 $, $ F=0 $, $ G=1 $, $ e=0 $, show that $ a(t)=X(uo,vo+t) $ is a straight curve

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves

Let $X : U \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular surface with $E =1 + v^2$  , $F = 0$ , $G=1$ , $e=0$
Show that the curve $ a(t)=X(uo,vo+t)$ (for constant $ (uo,vo) $ at $ U $ and $ t $ belong at $ (-\epsilon,\epsilon) $) is straight.

where $ E=\mathopen{<}Xu,Xu\mathclose{>} $, $ G=\mathopen{<}Xv,Xv\mathclose{>} $, $ F=\mathopen{<}Xu,Xv\mathclose{>} $ and $ e=\mathopen{<}N,Xuu\mathclose{>} $, $ g=\mathopen{<} N,Xvv \mathclose{>} $, $f=\mathopen{<}N,Xuu\mathclose{>}$, $ N $ is the Gauss map and $ Xu $, $ Xv $, $ Xuu $, $ Xvv$ are the first and second partial derivatives of $ X $.

To show that i think we have to show that $ a''(t)=0 $ for every $ t \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon) $.
but $ a''(t)=Xvv(uo,vo+t) $. From Christoffel's symbols we can show that $ Xvv=gN $
So that is not zero...  Am i thinking something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only because $a'$ has constant length $1$ can you say you want to show $a''=0$. In general, the $v$-curves will be lines if and only if $X_{vv}$ is a multiple of $X_v$ at every point.

OK, so here's what you need to do. Calculate the Gaussian curvature, using $E$ and $G$, and then compare this with the extrinsic formula for the Gaussian curvature (in terms of $E,F,G$ and $e,f,g$). You should get a formula for $f$ and see that it depends only on $v$. Then use one of the Codazzi equations to deduce that $g=0$ (because $e_v-f_u=0=-g\Gamma^2_{11}$ and $\Gamma^2_{11}\ne 0$).

By the way, a helicoid admits such a parametrization with the $u$-curves helices and the $v$-curves lines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! First sorry for the confusion , i change it ! Second genneraly if we have a curve $a$ with $ a''(t) =0$ can't we take that is a straight curve? Last i found that g is not zero . So probably i am wrong.

Comment: Sure, *if* $a''(t)=0$, then $a'(t)$ is constant, which means you have a straight line. But I'm saying that in general you could have a particle moving along a straight line with nonzero acceleration. ... Now, how did you find that $g\ne 0$? I don't see any way to calculate $g$ directly!

Comment: first i found the $f$ and after that I used one of Mainardi Codazzi equation , $fv - gu$ =$eΓ^1_{22}+f(Γ^2_{11} -Γ^1_{12}) -gΓ^2_{12}$

Comment: so after that i found $gu$ so i found $g$

Comment: Try the *other* Codazzi equation (as I suggested in my original answer). However, if you use the Codazzi equation you did, you do in fact get $g_u=0$, but that's not good enough to find $g$ !!

Comment: you are right , i can get $g=\int gu du + h(v) $ , but if $g=0$ then $ gu = 0 $ right?

Comment: i am telling that because i didnt find $ gu$ =0

Comment: Well, you *should* have found $g_u=0$ if you did everything correctly. But I'm telling you to use the *other* Codazzi equation, which gives you information directly about $g$, not $g_u$. (I'm guessing you have $f$ wrong. Do you have $f=1/\sqrt{1+v^2}$? (By the way, please accept the answer when you're satisfied that we're done!) :)

Comment: yes of course i will do , i didn't do it already because we are discusing :) , i will try the other one  but yes i found the same f . Thank you very much for your help!!